# Query selecting common part of selected records

Tags: sql, vba

I have a problem with constructing simple query, only very complicated using count function comes to my mind.

Here is Table:

```
ID | A | B
-----------
 1 | 1 | 1
 2 | 1 | 2
 3 | 1 | 3
 4 | 1 | 4
 5 | 2 | 1
 6 | 2 | 2
 7 | 2 | 5
 8 | 2 | 6
 9 | 3 | 1
10 | 3 | 3
11 | 3 | 7
```

I need to get from that values B, which exist in every selected A.
So for example from this table for A = 1 and 2 output is B = 1 and 2

My plan is to take all B, which are in selected A using function IN. And then using function COUNT to count every B and if it is equal to number of selected A it is right.

My second is based on loop. I use VBA, so the first query will be to find all B which A=1, then from all B which were found in previous step find that, which A=2 and so on.
However it will be very complicated.

What's your opinion about that.

Thank You for any reply.

Examples:

```
A in {1,2} => Output: B = {1,2},
because B = 1 is with A = 1 for ID = 1
and B = 1 is with A = 2 for ID = 5
(similar way with B = 2)
B = 3 is with A = 1 for ID = 3, but it is not with B for any ID
A in {1, 2, 3} => Output: B = {1},
A in {1, 3} => Output: B = {1, 3},
A in {2, 3} => Output: B = {1}
```

Comment: Can't you use output of easy sql query? SELECT A from tableX INTERSECT
SELECT B FROM tableX   ?

Comment: No, the output of Your query will be 1,2,3.
I dont need numbers which appears in Column A and in Column B. I need those B which appears in selected by me A.
In this example when I take A = 1,2,3 output will be only 1

A = 1,2 => B = 1,2

A = 1,3 => B = 1,3
A = 2,3 => B = 1
because those B are in every selected A

Comment: No, the output of Your query will be 1,2,3.
I dont need numbers which appears in Column A and in Column B. I need those B which appears in selected by me A.
In this example when I take A = 1,2,3 output will be only 1

|A = 1,2 => B = 1,2 
|A = 1,3 => B = 1,3
|A = 2,3 => B = 1, 
because those B are in every selected A

Comment: Then your 1. plan is better, it doesn't need any loop. Did you write any code?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.b 
FROM (SELECT b FROM tablex WHERE A = val1) a
JOIN (SELECT b FROM tablex WHERE A = val2) b ON a.b=b.b
```

Untested.

Comment: Yep, but I didn't write that there are two A values.
There can be more A values